# PostgreSQL ts_stat in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, full-text-search, tsvector

Postgres uses an odd syntax for `ts_stat` queries where it includes a literal string containing the statement that you want statistics on, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM ts_stat('SELECT content_ts FROM document_contents')
ORDER BY nentry DESC, ndoc DESC, word;
```

I would like to use a `Query` object in SQLAlchemy to work up a complex query with lots of optional filters like:

```
SELECT content_ts 
FROM document_contents
JOIN fact_api ON document_contents.id = fact_api.content_id 
WHERE fact_api.day >= %(day_1)s
AND fact_api.day <= %(day_2)s
AND fact_api.unit IN (%(unit_1)s)
AND fact_api.term IN (%(term_1)s, %(term_2)s)
```

I have SQLAlchemy code which generates that inner query. Is there a good way to generate the `ts_stat` query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hide the actual compiling in a [custom `FunctionElement`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/compiler.html):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import FunctionElement, column
from sqlalchemy.sql.base import ColumnCollection
from sqlalchemy.types import TEXT, INTEGER


class ts_stat(FunctionElement):
    name = "ts_stat"

    @property
    def columns(self):
        # Using (undocumented) `_selectable=self` would allow
        # omitting the explicit `select_from(ts_stat_obj)` in
        # every query using `ts_stat`.
        return ColumnCollection(
            column("word", TEXT),
            column("ndoc", INTEGER),
            column("nentry", INTEGER))

@compiles(ts_stat, 'postgresql')
def pg_ts_stat(element, compiler, **kw):
    kw.pop("asfrom", None)  # Ignore and set explicitly
    arg1, = element.clauses
    # arg1 is a FromGrouping, which would force parens around the SELECT.
    stmt = compiler.process(
        arg1.element, asfrom=False, literal_binds=True, **kw)
    # TODO: Choose a random tag for dollar quoting. Another option
    # would be to wrap the stmt in `literal()`, compiling that, and
    # letting the driver worry about quoting.
    return f"ts_stat($${stmt}$$)"
```

Usage is straightforward: you pass a `Select` or a `Query` as the sole argument:

```
from sqlalchemy import select, column, literal
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

d = postgresql.dialect()

s = select([1])
f = ts_stat(s)
stmt = select([f.c.word, f.c.ndoc, f.c.nentry]).\
    select_from(f).\
    order_by(f.c.nentry.desc(),
             f.c.ndoc.desc(),
             f.c.word).\
    compile(dialect=d)
print(stmt)
# SELECT word, ndoc, nentry 
# FROM ts_stat($$SELECT 1$$) ORDER BY nentry DESC, ndoc DESC, word

Session = sessionmaker()
session = Session()

q = session.query(literal(1))
f2 = ts_stat(q)
stmt2 = select(['*']).\
    select_from(f2).\
    order_by(f2.c.nentry.desc(),
             f2.c.ndoc.desc(),
             f2.c.word).\
    compile(dialect=d)
print(stmt2)
# SELECT * 
# FROM ts_stat($$SELECT 1 AS param_1$$) ORDER BY nentry DESC, ndoc DESC, word
```

Note that using `literal_binds=True` limits what you can pass as parameters to the inner select, as explained in ["How do I render SQL expressions as strings, possibly with bound parameters inlined?"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined).

Of course such a construct makes it non-obvious to other readers that the DB function `ts_stat()` accepts a string argument in reality, but perhaps in this case the convenience of it triumphs.

Comment: Thanks. It is probably nicer to treat it as a function.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
query = session.query( ... lots of joins ... )
literal_query = str(query.statement.compile(engine, compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))
ts_stat = text('SELECT * FROM ts_stat($$' + 
               literal_query + 
               '$$) ORDER BY nentry DESC, ndoc DESC, word')
for row in session.execute(ts_stat):
    print(row)
```

See this for getting the query:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/sqlexpressions.html

And this for `$$`:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING

Comment: But I would love to know if there's a way to do this without using `text` like this.